# Convert angle-axis angular velocity to euler angular velocity using Eigen

Tags: eigen

Given an angular velocity represented by the vector `[x, y, z]` where the magnitude of the vector represents the magnitude of the angular velocity in radians/s and the direction of the vector represents the axis in which the rotation is applied, how do I convert this vector into body-fixed euler angular velocity (`roll_d`, `pitch_d`, `yaw_d`)?

Answer (score 0):

For infinitesimally small timesteps body-fixed angular velocity and "Euler angular velocity" are the same.

To convert from world-frame angular velocity to body-fixed angular velocity you need to rotate the vector from the world frame to the body frame, using the current orientation of your vehicle.

Comment: So you're saying that once I rotate vector `[x, y, z]` by the rotation on the body to `[x2, y2, z2]`, `x2` is equal to `roll_d` (body-fixed x rotation), `y2` is equal to `pitch_d` (body-fixed y rotation) and `z2` is equal to `yaw_d` (body-fixed z rotation)?